# Reference 'this' type in java generic interface

Tags: java, generics

#### I want to reference `this` **class type** in generic interface.

I need this to enforce interface implementations to implement two methods which return implementations of generic classes with `this` **class type as generic parameter**.

**Let's assume I have two interfaces: `Cover.java` and `Adaptor.java`**

```java
interface Cover<P extends Phone> {
    P getPhone();
}

interface Adaptor<P extends Phone> {
    P getPhone();
}
```

**I want to create generic interface, that encourage it's implementations to return `Cover` and `Adaptor` with itself as generic parameter**

```java
// <T> should reference to current Phone implementation
public interface Phone {
   Cover<T> getCover();
   Adaptor<T> getAdaptor();
}
```

**As a result I want:**

```java
//correct
public class Iphone implements Phone {
   Cover<Iphone> getCover(); // <- I want this to be compile-time controlled
   Adaptor<Iphone> getAdaptor(); // <- I want this to be compile-time controlled
}

// compile-time exception
public class Samsung implements Phone {
  Cover<Iphone> getCover(); // <- CTE
   Adaptor<Iphone> getAdaptor(); // <- CTE
}
```

Is there any way to achieve this in Java 7?